# Magento 2 match header search layout for mobile and desktop

Tags: magento2, frontend, header

> I'm wondering if there is a way to replace the desktop header search
>   element (search input box) with the way it is implemented in mobile
>   (show only a search icon, and when you click it the search input field
>   appears below), preferably purely through css/js, but editing
>   templates works as well.

Comment: You want this withi default Luma theme or any custom theme you are using ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya using a custom theme based on the Magento blank theme.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out on my own, after tinkering with CSS.